# PYTHON 3.3.1 - Using urllib to directly open a file, code gets stuck at a specific line

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

I'm trying to write a Python program to deal with RSS, however I'm having some issues downloading the files directly from the internet.

I am using urllib.request.urlopen() to get the files. Here is the bit of code that I am having trouble with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import urllib.request as urlget

self.sourceUrl = sourceUrl       #sourceUrl was an argument
self.root = et.fromstring(urlget.urlopen(sourceUrl).read())
```

I have tracked the problem down to a single line:

```
urllib.request.urlopen calls urllib.request.opener.open()  
    which then calls self._open()  
    which then calls self._call_chain()  
    which then calls urllib.request.HTTPHandler.http_open()  
    which then calls urllib.request.AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open()  
    which then calls http.client.HTTPConnection.getresponse()  
    which then calls http.client.HTTTResponse.begin()  
    which then calls self._read_status()
```

Problem line (found by being the only line to appear upon pausing execution many times):
Python33\Lib\http\client.py Line 317

```
if len(line) > _MAXLINE:
```

I can continue the code, but only if I babysit it through Step Over until I get back to my code.

In my tests, this problem never occurred, so I can't think if why I am getting it now.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:** Source can be found [here](https://github.com/asilearnprogramming/BasicRSSReader). I lost motivation to work on this project quite some time ago, and haven't touched it since. I might redo the entire thing if I get some more motivation, but I don't expect to any time soon. If you wish to answer, I invite you to have at it, it might be beneficial to others. Be warned, however, that the code is terrible, as at the time I had relatively little experience. I can't really find my way around it, but I've figured out that you have to look at data/code/functions.py

Also note, that, as far as I can remember, it wasn't calling an error, it was just that the program was hanging for minutes at a time before I got impatient.

Comment: Could you please add the full system trace?

Answer (score 0):

Without more code, it will be hard to help you. What is the URL of your feed. What does it return when you try to simply access it.

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 01:25:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
>>> import urllib.request as urlget
>>> sourceurl = "http://www.la-grange.net/feed"
>>> root = et.fromstring(urlget.urlopen(sourceurl).read())
>>> root
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed' at 0x1013a82b8>
>>>
```